# jQuery Animate div position

Tags: jquery

I want to animate a div by changing it's top property like so:

```
var loadingFrame = 1; loadingFrame = (loadingFrame + 1) % 12;

// Loading animation
jQuery('div.ModalLoading div').animate('top', (loadingFrame * -40) + 'px');
```

The idea is that the inner div will look like it is sliding up inside the ModalLoading div, and needs to continue infinite. At the moment the div is stationary. Thanks.

EDIT: This based upon the loading in FancyBox --> http://fancybox.net/ if that helps anyone debug my code.

```
div.ModalLoading
{
    height: 40px; width: 40px; margin: 0 auto 20px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1104; position: relative;
}
div.ModalLoading div
{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 40px; height: 480px; background: url('loading.png');
}
```

Comment: Did you set divs CSS to be `position: absolute;`?

Comment: Yes I'll add the CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, ive just tried and the best i can do is this.

```
var loadingFrame = 1; loadingFrame = (loadingFrame + 1) % 12;

function startLoader(loopint,_left,_right)
{
    settings = {};
    if(_left && !_right)
    {
        settings.left = (((loadingFrame + 1) % 12) * -40)
        var _callback = function(){startLoader(loopint,false,true)}
    }else{
        settings.left = (((loadingFrame + 1) % 12) * +40)
        var _callback = function(){startLoader(loopint,true,false)}
    }

    jQuery('.inner').animate(settings,loopint,_callback);
}
```

and start the animation.

```
startLoader(5000);
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/v8rvM/2/

​

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. However I want to only animate one way and repeat over and over with no delay.